# Option list showing undefined values on ajax output

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

this is my code to show values in list box.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: queryvalue,
    url: "inputaction.php",

    success: function (data) {
        switch (action) {
            case "GetMake":
                console.log(data);
                var select = $("#promake");
                select.empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {
                    select.append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].make + '</option>');
                }
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

i get the result of lot of undefined values in select field. and i have attached an console result in image file, in console output is correct how to rectify this problem.

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr1ha.png)

[Page Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRWOj.png)

```
$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['type']);
            $make = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['make']);
            $query = "select * from assetmodel where typeid = '".$type."' AND makeid = '".$make."' ORDER by model ASC";
            $result = RunQuery($query, $conn);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $re = array(
                    'id' => $row['id'],
                    'model' => $row['model']
                );
            }
            echo json_encode($re);
```

this is my action page

Comment: Where does the "action" variable come from?

Comment: some code in before this i have not shown here for not to confuse..

Answer (score 2):

You have to use "JSON.parse":

```
var select = $("#promake");
select.empty();
var parse = JSON.parse(json);
for (var i = 0; i < parse.length; i++)
{
      select.append('<option value="' + parse[i].id + '">' + parse[i].make + '</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

decode the json in success

```
success: function (data) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(data);
    switch (action) {
        case "GetMake":
            console.log(data);
            var select = $("#promake");
            select.empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                select.append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].make + '</option>');
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the dataType as `json`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: queryvalue,
    url: "inputaction.php",
```

> ```
>     dataType: "json",
> ```

```
    success: function (data) {
        switch (action) {
```

and set the MIME type of your response to `application/json` before sending the data:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($re);
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: when using var parse = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < parse.length; i++)
                                    {
                                        select.append('<option value="' + parse[i].id + '">' + parse[i].make + '</option>');
                                    }

Comment: I didn't tell you to use JSON.parse ... are you combining two different answers?

Comment: when using header('Content-Type: application/json') no output in console

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix in client-side is as below. Just a condition check inside your loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    if (typeof data[i].id != "undefined" && typeof data[i].make != "undefined" ) {
        select.append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].make + '</option>');
    }
}
```

If you want to have clean data from DB itself, you have to repair your query. That will eliminate the root cause.